# How to cache remoteEntry.js in host application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, caching, webpack-module-federation

I am using ModuleFederationPlugin to render remote app in host app. I was running the production build in local for both app, I want to cache the remoteEntry.js in host app such that it loads only when the content are changed else it should load from cache

Comment: I would look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox